# Add gamepad/game controller support to flutter app tried many libraries but none working

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, gamepad, gamepad-api, gamecontroller

i tried many libraries none of those working  i tried native code in flutter but method cannont be continuosly invoked
any suggestions

Adding support of gamepads to Flutter app

Also are there any ways to add support of game controllers connected via bluetooth that would also solve the problem

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.